OpenVPN 3 is inoperable as it tries to access nonexistent directories
I have installed openvpn3 as described here on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine. I tried using my config files which have worked on many other macOS, iOS, and Windows machines:
$ openvpn3 config-import --config config.ovpn

This appears to be successful...
Configuration imported.  Configuration path: /net/openvpn/v3/configuration/fab974dexaecbx40d7xafa5xa2e9d040d9f0

But /net, let alone all the subdirectories, doesn't exist on my machine.
$ ls /net
ls: cannot access '/net': No such file or directory

Similarly, when trying to use the profile, nothing happens.
$ openvpn3 session-start --config config.ovpn
Using pre-loaded configuration profile 'config.ovpn'
Session path: /net/openvpn/v3/sessions/f7e44ebesc9e9s4eefs988es9f0674d386b3
[hang]
[ctrl-c]

Using this config with the openvpn version in the default Ubuntu repositories (2.5.9) works with the exception of DNS, but that's a separate issue (that I was hoping OpenVPN 3 would fix).
This seems like a rather fundamental problem, and I am very surprised by the complete lack of error messages, in fact saying things are successful when writing to directories that simply don't exist. Am I missing something obvious here?

I don't think /net is supposed to be a directory, is it? rather it's a component of the DBUS object path

I suspect it will be easier to fix your issue with the normal version of openvpn than to try to figure out this new version. The old version is tricky enough.

@steeldriver Ah, that makes more sense. "Path" and the fact that I've seen /net on some systems confused me. Still doesn't explain why nothing happens when I start the session...

@mpboden Typo in post (fixed)
